# como cambiar a tipo fecha?

Tags: r, datetime, date

tengo el siguiente vector.

```
x<-c("2021-04-22","2020-08-10","2021-03-16","2020-09-16")
```

que función tendría que usar para cambiarlo por:

`22/04/2021, 10/08/2020, 16/03/2021 y 16/09/2020`.

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: consulta este link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116411/4668184

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("2021-04-22","2020-08-10","2021-03-16","2020-09-16")
x_fecha <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
as.character(x_fecha, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

`as.date()` crea un vector de la clase `Date`. Con el argumento `format =` pasamos una cadena con el formato de fecha, en este caso AÑO en 4 dígitos (eso es `%Y`), mes (`%m`) y día (`%d`).
Cuando llamamos es objeto se imprime según el `locale` de `R`. Para que se imprima con el formato que nos guste usamos `as.character()` y pasamos el formato indicando en qué lugar van el día, mes y año.

## Tabla de símbolos para fechas

```
Símbolo   Significado 
--------- -------------------------------
%d        Día como número
%a        Día de la semana (abreviatura)
%A        Día de la semana
%m        Mes en número
%b        Mes en letras (abreviado)
%B        Mes en letras
%y        Año en número (dos dígitos)
%Y        Año en número (4 dígitos)
```

Fuente:https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Sirven tanto para especificar el formato de entrada en `as.Date` como el de salida en `as.character.Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he realizado de esta manera.

```
x<-gsub("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})", "\\3\\/\\2\\/\\1", x)
```

Estoy seguro que hay una manera más óptima de lograr los resultados.

Espero su ayuda, **muchas gracias de antemano.**